# Парсинг текста UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, синтаксический-анализ

Помогите решить проблемку.

Надо заменить текст такой:
Вишня вкус.укр.
На такой:
Вишня вкусная украинская

код:

```
$text = "Вишня вкус.укр.";
$p[0] = "вкус.";
$p[1] = "укр.";
$pattern[0] = "/".$p[0]."/";
$pattern[1] = "/".$p[1]."/";
$replacement[0] = "вкусная ";
$replacement[1] = "украинская ";
$z = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

В презультате $z содержит "Вишня вкусная раинская", стирается буква следующего слова. Кодировка UTF-8.
Есть идеи?

Comment: а чем str_replace() не устраивает?

Comment: Разве нельзя так? "/вкус\./"

У Вас такое ощущение, будто переменную вставляете.

Comment: str_replace() с UTF-8 плохо отрабатывает.
да вставляю переменную

Решение экранировать точки в $pattern

Answer (score 1):

У меня всё работает в UTF-8

```
$text = "Вишня вкус.укр.";
$p[0] = "вкус.";
$p[1] = "укр.";
$patterns[0] = "/".$p[0]."/";
$patterns[1] = "/".$p[1]."/";
$replacements[0] = "вкусная ";
$replacements[1] = "украинская ";
echo $text."<br />";
$z = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
echo $z."<br />";
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в коде (помечена комментарием):

```
$text = "Вишня вкус.укр.";
$p[0] = "вкус.";
$p[0] = "укр."; // наверно индекс должен быть равен одному?)
$pattern[0] = "/".$p[0]."/";
$pattern[1] = "/".$p[1]."/";
```

Comment: да индекс равен одному, но это не решает проблему

Comment: @BArS не знаю, у меня документ в "UTF-8 без BOM" после замены индекса на выходе получается: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0vp-1ea

Comment: хмм интересно....